# Checking my balance of my btc public adress outside of my Xapo account

Tags: wallet

I have a doubt regarding my balance account in my Xapo wallet. I have checked in blockchain.info and other pages with my btc public address and all of them gave me zero founds.. According to Xapo i have 0.00649539 btc (just as an example).

I havent made any transactions yet but shouldnt be at least one with my original founds transferred by this company to my bitcoin address ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I havent made any transactions yet but shouldnt be at least one with my original founds transferred by this company to my bitcoin address ????

No. Xapo is a service that holds your Bitcoin for you, kind of like how a bank holds your cash for you. When you deposit money in your Xapo wallet, what you are really doing is giving Xapo your money and getting a promise from them that when you want to send your money elsewhere. So the addresses that you deposited to are not actually yours; they are Xapo's and they are free to do whatever they want with that money.

When you decide to send your Bitcoin elsewhere, your Bitcoin will likely come from addresses which are not the ones that you deposited money into but rather addresses which someone else deposited money into. Those addresses are still Xapo's and they are fulfilling their promise to send the Bitcoin to wherever you specified.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, i already suppouse that but i just wanted an experienced confirmation!! Today earlier i made a test sending some btc to my blockchain wallet and indeed come from an unknown address fm xapo